# How to get package name of apk path?

Tags: java, android, manifest

I have a path of `apk` file in sd-card and i need to get the package name of that file.

Is there any way to get application package name from the apk file in android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The apk is just a zip container - so you could unzip the apk and extract the manifest and parse the packagename from it. There might be a more convenient way to do this - but I am not aware of it

Comment: yeah i can unzip. but `manifest.xml` is coded. How to parse it?

Comment: you might use the code of apktool for this http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/

Comment: Tnq, But i want to be client side, can i install or import apktool to my app?!

Comment: APKtool is just a jar - you might just add it as a dependency and call the right functions.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Android Asset Packaging Tool (aapt)

`aapt dump badging /path/to/app.apk | grep package:\ name`

Comment: I needed a client side way for users not for dev